# A particular scenario doesn't gets recorded in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a field where numerals can be entered in a particular way only. It will allow only 4 numerals. Initially the field is blank.

On clicking inside the field there is a separator `**:**` After entering numerals it will be like `12:12`. I don't know to mention what type of text box it is (Like autocomplete or free form)

While recording using IDE these actions are not getting recorded. I tried to write by my own. But cannot see any helpful links. I'm a newbie to Selenium. 
Checked using F12.

Can see as below

```
<input value ="" tabindex="10" maxlength="5" data-type="time" class="FormField textbox1" onfocus="return addTimePicker(this)" onblur="return checkTime(this)" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution like this :

Command : type

Target : `xpath=/html/body/form/div[4]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/input[1]`
Value :
1010

Then I need to write another command again. Else the value wont be retained. Field is restricted in such a way.

Command : click

Target : `xpath=/html/body/form/div[4]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/input[1]`

Is there any way to combine these two commands. The action i would like to perform is type in and then click inside the same field.